# Python/Flask/Jinja - getting values to Python dictionary for randomly generated keys

Tags: python, flask, request, jinja2

I have small problem with my code.
I try to get values from site to be stored in python dictionary.
Problem is range of values is randomly generated so I cannot attach it to different variables. I think I should use Jinja template for this, but I just cannot figure out how. Could you help my somehow or let me know, where to look for an answer? Thank you in advance.

Point 1: Code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import random


app = Flask (__name__)

@app.route('/')
def random_numbers_range():
    random.randrange(2, 20)
    list_numbers = []
    for i in range (random.randrange(2, 20)):
        list_numbers.append(i)
    return render_template('list.html', list_numbers = list_numbers)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = False, port = 1234)
```

Point 2: Jinja template to create windows for value input and submit button

```
  <!doctype html>
  {% for i in list_numbers %}
    <li>Number: <b>{{i}}</b></li>
        <div><label>Name it: <input type="text" name="powod"></label></div>        
  {% endfor %}
  <a href='/add_submit'><button>Submit</button></a>
  </ol>
```

Point 3: Site looks
[Site looks screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rI5P7.png)

Point 3: Expected output
[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VHV3.png)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Maybe someone will use it.

1.Server code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import random


app = Flask (__name__)
randing = []

@app.route('/')
def random_numbers_range():
    global randing
    randing = []
    random_number = random.randrange(2, 8)
    for i in range(2,random_number):
        randing.append(i)
    
    list_numbers = []
    for i in range (2, random_number):
        list_numbers.append(i)
    return render_template('list.html', list_numbers = list_numbers)


@app.route('/add_submit')
def add_submit():
    global username_from_form
    username_from_form = {}
    for i in range (0, max(randing)+1):
        if request.args.get(str (i)) == None:
            continue
        else:
            username_from_form[i] = request.args.get(str (i))
    return "Good job"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = False, port = 1234)
```

2.Template:

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Dodawanie nazwy liczby</title>
<form action='/add_submit' method="GET">
  {% for i in list_numbers %}
    <li>Number: <b>{{i}}</b></li>
        <div><label>Name it: <input type="text" name={{i}}></label></div>        
  {% endfor %}
  <a href='/add_submit'><button>Submit</button></a>
</form>
  </ol>
```